# Counting and ordered triplets

Tags: combinatorics

[image]

For the first part i get 4  and for second part i get 12,but for the last part, i am a bit stuck on how to answer it?

Answer (score 1):

You have a total of $10$ squares, so the answer to (c) would be $$10\cdot 4\cdot 100=4000.$$ 
This is obtained by multiplying the number of squares by the number of cubes by the number of elements $z\in S$, which has the combinatorial meaning of calculating the number of triples required.

Answer (score 1):

The squares in $S$ are: $1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81,100$. So there are $10$ squares in $S$.

The cubes in $S$ are: $1, 8, 27, 64$. So there are $4$ cubes in $S$.

$z$ can be free to be any number from $1$ to $100$. So there are $100$ choices for $z$.

The answer for part c) is: $10\times 4\times 100 = 4000$ ordered triples.

Comment: shouldn't it be the intersection of the squares and the cubes *100

Comment: oh right so doubling is allowed.